# Why is Xcode saying my class implementation is incomplete?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, singleton

I have created a singleton for my MusicBackground. And I receive a line code of imcomplete implementation of this line  @implementation MyBgMusic. Can anyone tell me why ? Below is the code:

```
#import "MyBgMusic.h"

static MyBgMusic *sharedMyManager = nil;

@implementation MyBgMusic

@synthesize player,playBgMusic;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (MyBgMusic*)sharedInstance {

    static MyBgMusic *_sharedInstance;
    if(!_sharedInstance) {
        static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
        dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
            _sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
            });
        }

        return _sharedInstance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {    

    return [self sharedInstance];
}


- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;    
}

#if (!__has_feature(objc_arc))

- (id)retain {  

    return self;    
}

- (unsigned)retainCount {
    return UINT_MAX;  //denotes an object that cannot be released
}


- (id)autorelease {

    return self;    
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [MyBgMusic release];
    [playBgMusic release];
    [player release];
    [super dealloc];
}
#endif

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Custom Methods

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"];
    self.player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL]; 
    player.delegate = self;
    [player play];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [super viewDidLoad];


}

@end
```

For the M file, below is the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@interface MyBgMusic : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {


    AVAudioPlayer *player;
    UIButton *playBgMusic;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet AVAudioPlayer *player;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *playBgMusic;


+ (id)sharedManager;
-(IBAction) toggleMusic;


@end
```

And how do I reference to my toggle button: Below is the code :

```
- (IBAction)toggleMusic {

    if ([self.player isPlaying] == YES) {
        [self.player stop]; 
    } else {
        [self.player play];
    }
    self.playBgMusic.enabled = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means your `@implementation` section does not contain everything described in the `@interface` section.

I can see two problems.

First you need to place this code:

```
- (IBAction)toggleMusic {

    ...

}
```

Somewhere in between `@implementation` and `@end`.

And you also need to rename the line `+ (MyBgMusic*)sharedInstance` to `+ (id)sharedManager`.

EDIT:

To access the toggle music method elsewhere in your code, you would do:

```
[[MyBgMusic sharedManager] toggleMusic];
```

Comment: Hi, the incomplete implementation solved. But how do i reference my toggle button from the singleton file from this toggle button? - (IBAction)toggleMusic { if ([self.player isPlaying] == YES) { [self.player stop]; } else { [self.player play]; } self.playBgMusic.enabled = YES; }

Comment: I've updated my answer to answer that as well, assuming I've understood what you're trying to do?

Comment: How to declare that in my SecondViewController? Here is my latest update code : - (IBAction)toggleMusic {
    
    
    if ([[[MyBgMusic sharedManager] player] isPlaying] == YES) {
        [[[MyBgMusic sharedManager] player] stop]; 
    } else {
        [[[MyBgMusic sharedManager] player] play];
    }
    
    
}

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Maybe ask it as a separate question and post the full code with newlines and so on. It's hard to read code in a comment.

Comment: Ok i will do post a new question.

Comment: Here is the new [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455576/ios-how-to-reference-a-music-background-from-a-singleton-class)

Answer (score 1):

It means that your `MyBgMusic` class isn't doing everything it promised to do in its header file, which includes being a `UIViewController` and implementing the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` protocol.  I'm not familiar with exactly what the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` is, but it's quite possible that your class doesn't implement all of the required methods.

Also, you're declaring methods `+(id)sharedManager` and `-(IBAction)toggleMusic`, but I don't see them anywhere in the implementation file.  That would be a case of promising something in the header and not implementing it in the class.

It would help if you posted the actual error message.

Comment: It just a yellow line error of incomplete implementation
Only this line code @implementation MyBgMusic

Comment: Hi, the incomplete implementation solved. But how do i reference my toggle button from the singleton file from this toggle button?


- (IBAction)toggleMusic {

    if ([self.player isPlaying] == YES) {
        [self.player stop]; 
    } else {
        [self.player play];
    }
    self.playBgMusic.enabled = YES;

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `+(id)sharedManager`implementation is called `+(id)sharedInstance`. Just guessing, but it seems they are supposed to do the same.